# PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]:

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am receiving the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 
'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error 
in your SQL syntax;
```

However, I am unable to resolve.  The line number says it is 15 which is

```
$res->execute(array_values($params));
```

Can you spot the problem?

```
function fetchBgnew(array $conditions){ 
    $db = Core::getInstance();              
    $sql = "SELECT p.id, p.bg, p.bg_desc, p.bg_id, p.user_id, p.panel_id, p.domainurl, 
                   p.type, p.price 
              FROM ".USERS_BG." as p 
              left join ".USERS." as u on p.user_id=u.id WHERE u.status !=0 and 1 and";
    $params = array();
    foreach ($conditions as $column => $value) {
        if (preg_match('/^[a-z]+$/', $column)) {
            $sql .= "$column = ?";
            $params[] = $value;
            $sql .= "group by p.id desc, LIMIT 0,25";
        }
    }                
    $res = $db->dbh->prepare($sql);
    $res->execute(array_values($params));                
    $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $sql="SELECT p.id FROM ".USERS_BG." as p 
            left join ".USERS." as u on p.user_id=u.id WHERE u.status !=0 and";
    $params = array();
    foreach ($conditions as $column => $value) {
        if (preg_match('/^[a-z]+$/', $column)) {
            $sql .= "$column = ? group by p.id desc LIMIT 0,25";
            $params[] = $value;
        }
    }
    $cnt = $db->dbh->prepare($sql);
    $cnt->execute(array_values($params));           
    $cnt->rowCount();

    return $result = array("data"=>$res, "count"=>$cnt);
}
function fetchUser(array $conditions){       
    $db = Core::getInstance();
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM ruj_users_jel WHERE";
    $params = array();
    foreach ($conditions as $column => $value) {
        if (preg_match('/^[a-z]+$/', $column)) {
            $sql .= "$column = ?";
            $params[] = $value;
        }
    }

    $res = $db->dbh->prepare($sql);
    $res->execute(array_values($params));
    $numrows = $res->rowCount();

return $numrows;


}
$bgdataarr = fetchBgnew(array("p.status"=>'1'));

$bgdata = $bgdataarr['data'];

$page_title = "Home";
foreach($bgdata as $brag){
    print_r($bgdata[$i]['countjellys']=fetchUser(array('brag_id'=>$bg['id']))); 
}
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation - it's impossible to read your code like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the (correct...) answer of @TomvanderWoerdt: Your sql statement is not valid, you can only add a `LIMIT` clause once at the end.

The same applies to the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: I actually mentioned this ("*imagine what happens with 2 fields*") but yes, this.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt Strange, but it seems you have edited your answer since I first saw it.

Comment: @jeroen I am not sure what you mean about the LIMIT clause. I only need it at the end of the SQL statement. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @Claude Grecea You should add your ´LIMIT´ AND ´GROUP BY´ clauses after the loop, not in the loop. And the ´LIMIT´ clause without a comma before it. Can you echo out the complete sql statement that you are preparing?

Comment: @jeroen I understand now about not putting the sql statement in the loop. I was reading the code wrong. Since then I have made the changes and I am now receiving a an error. here is the sql statement                                                       $sql = "SELECT p.id,p.brag,p.brag_desc,p.brag_id,p.user_id, p.panel_id,p.domainurl,p.type,p.price FROM ruj_users_brag as p left join ruj_users as u on p.user_id=u.id WHERE u.status !=0 and 1 and p.status = 1 GROUP BY p.id DESC LIMIT 25";

Comment: @jeroen I just figured out. Amon the other issues you mentioned I also was missing a period in `preg_match('/^[a-z-.]+$/')` . Thanks again.

Comment: @jeroen If I had 2 values and pairs and I wanted to separate them by an 'AND' like so `$column = ? AND $column = ?` . How would I accomplish this within the code that I have?

Comment: @Claude Grecea I think you would need to post a new question with the actual code, but looking at what you have, you would have to move the `and` into the loop and the `GROUP BY` and `LIMIT` to after the loop.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're forgetting the spaces.

```
$sql = "SELECT p.id,p.bg,p.bg_desc,p.bg_id,p.user_id, p.panel_id,p.domainurl,p.type,p.price FROM ".USERS_BG." as p left join ".USERS." as u on p.user_id=u.id WHERE u.status !=0 and 1 and";
...
$sql .= "$column = ?";
...
$sql .= "group by p.id desc, LIMIT 0,25";
```

This will result in a statement like `SELECT ... andcolumn =` (note the missing space between 'and' and 'column')

Also, your `GROUP BY` syntax is incorrect (there shouldn't be a comma after DESC) and again missing a space. And imagine what happens if you have two fields?

Comment: thanks for your response. I have added the spaces and stripped out the comma and I still receive the same error. I have even executed the command in myphpadmin with success. Afterwards, plugged it and still the same error.